# bxSlider background-image flickers in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, bxslider

I have a little problem. I use bxSlider but instead of `<img>` I use `background-image`.
In chrome I see some flickering and I can't get rid of it. 
Maybe someone had a similar problem, tell me please how to treat :)

Here is my code

```js
$('.bxslider').bxSlider();
```

```css
.bxslider {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.bxslider li {
  height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1920/400/sports)"></li>
  <li style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1920/400/city)"></li>
</ul>
```

And you can also see it in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Narek_T/7mdxzb77/show/)

flicker seen in browser resolution 1700px and more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option [`useCSS`](http://bxslider.com/options) might be related to the flickers, set it to `false` and see.

> **`useCSS`**
>
> If `true`, CSS transitions will be used for horizontal and vertical
>   slide animations (this uses native hardware acceleration). If `false`,
>   jQuery `animate()` will be used.
>
> ```
> default: true
> options: boolean (true / false)
> ```

Comment: Thanks. Ok, and I finally figured it out. I'll answer in this question too, maybe it can help someone)

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out that. Thanks @Pangloss because his answer told me where to find the real problem. And the real problem is `-webkit-perspective` because bxSlider uses `transform: translate3d()`. About `-webkit-perspective` you can read here [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/), [here](https://davidwalsh.name/translate3d) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective).

In this particular situation my solution is `-webkit-perspective: 1000px;`. No flickers and we'll stay with CSS transforms without JS :)

Comment: Hi @Narek-T Where did you put -webkit-perspective: 1000px;? i'm having the same issue and i 'd rather not use useCSS: false.

Comment: Hi. For `.bxslider`

Comment: Hi Narek T, do you have a demo of your fix? I thought I had fixed it with your help but it's still there.